# Add parameter to report URL: Parameter is missing a value

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to insert an SSRS report in a webpart in SharePoint.  The report is a TFS Sprint Burndown chart.  For this, I need to generate the report using the following URL:

```
http://vhacpadev04/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/TfsReports/VAPARS+Team/Sprint+Burndown&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Parameters=true&rp:SprintParam=Release+2%5CSprint+1
```

The project name in TFS is *VAPARS Team*.  The sprint I'm trying to run this chart for is *Release 2 Sprint 1*.

Typically, the ReportViewer will prompt me for this parameter.  In this case, SprintParam:

[image]

However, when I hide this (using &rc:Parameters=false), then I get the following error:

[image: Missing parameter value message]

And here's the parameter properties for this report on SSRS:

[image: Parameter list]

I'm not sure how to format the URL to pass the correct sprint parameter.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if the answer to this question is drop dead simple, please let me know or provide a link to some relevant content.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a default value for SprintParam (even though you are overriding that in the URL) or you need to remove the dependency on the parameter if it is used for cascading parameters. The report thinks it cannot run without this information, even though you are supplying it in the URL. StartDateParam and EndDateParam are query based so I'm guessing those have a dependency on the SprintParam. That's what is causing the error to display and your URL parameters are ignored.

Comment: Should I just set the Default Value to Release 2\Sprint1 or is there a better, safer default value to use?  And should I still turn off Prompt User?  Thanks for you assistance, BTW.

Comment: I don't know your data, so I can't say what is "better, safer" but you need something there and that seems as a good a default value as any. You're fine leaving Prompt User unchecked.